# Random double Web Requests C# IIS7 PollLockedSessionCallback

Tags: c#, http, web, request

I sometimes have double web requests (no double clickers).
Can anyone please tell me what causes them, so I can prevent them?

**initial situation:**

It is a .Net 3.5 C# Application running in IIS7. No Asp.Net with ViewState. Just PageHandlers with 
Xml/Xslt Transformations.
The code is very old. This problem just appeared out of the blue some time ago.
We send emails there and thats how it popped up. We sometimes suddenly received two mails instead of one.

**My observations so far:**

It happens seldom, but nonetheless sometimes. Apparently random.
The Sent Bytes at the first Request are 0, but they are not double clickers. HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected is true.

**My assumptions so far:**

It seems that something goes wrong in the SessionHandling (via Sql-Server) and this reopens the request?

### IIS Log:

2012-03-02 08:16:43 W3SVC9026 [Server] [Server IP] POST [Internal URL] - 80 - [Client IP] HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+AskTbORJ/5.14.1.20007) ASP.NET_SessionId=[Session Id] [Absolute URL] [Host name] 200 0 64 0 899 937

2012-03-02 08:16:43 W3SVC9026 [Server] [Server IP] POST [internal URL] - 80 - [Client IP] HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+AskTbORJ/5.14.1.20007) ASP.NET_SessionId=[Session Id] [Absolute URL] [Host name] 200 0 0 45888 923 1343

### StackTrace:

**08:16:43 Regular Request (All normal requests which only run once look that way too)**

at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at [MyPageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) and so on]
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
at System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)

**08:16:44 Additional Request**

at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at [MyPageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) and so on]
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.ResumeStepsWithAssert(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean synchronous, Object result, Exception error, RequestNotificationStatus status)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.PollLockedSessionCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)

Comment: Is the page you are calling causing a `302` response?  This would cause a second request.

Comment: Hello, IIs Log has two 200 Responses

Comment: You have a custom HttpHandler.  What is this doing?